# Having problems with ctime, and working out function running time

Tags: c++, ctime

I'm having trouble working out the time for my two maxsubarray functions to run. (right at the bottom of the code)
The output it gives me:

```
 Inputsize: 101 Time using Brute Force:0 Time Using DivandCon: 12
```

is correct for the second time I use clock() but for the first difference `diff1` it just gives me `0` and I'm not sure why?

**Edit: Revised Code.**

**Edit2: Added Output.**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <limits.h>

using namespace std;

int Kedane(int a[], int size)
{
int max_so_far = 0, max_ending_here = 0;
int i;
for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    max_ending_here = max_ending_here + a[i];
    if(max_ending_here < 0)
        max_ending_here = 0;
    if(max_so_far < max_ending_here)
        max_so_far = max_ending_here;
}
return max_so_far;
}

int BruteForce(int array[],int n)
{
int sum,ret=0;

for(int j=-1;j<=n-2;j++)
{
    sum=0;
    for(int k=j+1;k<+n-1;k++)
    {
        sum+=array[k];

        if(sum>ret)
        {
            ret=sum;
        }
    }
}
return ret;
}
//------------------------------------------------------
// FUNCTION WHICH FINDS MAX OF 2 INTS
int max(int a, int b) { return (a > b)? a : b; }

// FUNCTION WHICH FINDS MAX OF 3 NUMBERS
// CALL MAX FUNCT FOR 2 VARIS TWICE!
int max(int a, int b, int c) { return max(max(a, b), c); }

// WORKS OUT FROM MIDDLE+1->RIGHT THE MAX SUM &
// THE MAX SUM FROM MIDDLE->LEFT + RETURNS SUM OF THESE
int maxCrossingSum(int arr[], int l, int m, int h)
{
int sum = 0;            // LEFT OF MID
int LEFTsum = INT_MIN;  // INITIALLISES SUM TO LOWEST POSSIBLE INT
for (int i = m; i >= l; i--)
{
    sum = sum + arr[i];
    if (sum > LEFTsum)
        LEFTsum = sum;
}

sum = 0;                // RIGHT OF MID
int RIGHTsum = INT_MIN;
for (int i = m+1; i <= h; i++)
{
    sum = sum + arr[i];
    if (sum > RIGHTsum)
        RIGHTsum = sum;
}

// RETURN SUM OF BOTH LEFT AND RIGHT SIDE MAX'S
return LEFTsum + RIGHTsum;
}
// Returns sum of maxium sum subarray in aa[l..h]
int maxSubArraySum(int arr[], int l, int h)
{
// Base Case: Only one element
if (l == h)
    return arr[l];

// Find middle point
int m = (l + h)/2;

/* Return maximum of following three possible cases
 a) Maximum subarray sum in left half
 b) Maximum subarray sum in right half
 c) Maximum subarray sum such that the subarray crosses the midpoint */
return max(maxSubArraySum(arr, l, m),
           maxSubArraySum(arr, m+1, h),
           maxCrossingSum(arr, l, m, h));
}

// DRIVER
int main(void)
{
std::srand (time(NULL));

// CODE TO FILL ARRAY WITH RANDOMS [-50;50]
int size=30000;
int array[size];

for(int i=0;i<=size;i++)
{
    array[i]=(std::rand() % 100) -50;
}

// TIMING VARI'S
clock_t t1,t2;
clock_t A,B;
clock_t K1,K2;
volatile int  mb, md, qq;

//VARYING ELEMENTS IN THE ARRAY
for(int  n=101;n<size;n=n+100)
{
    t1=clock();
    mb=BruteForce(array,n);
    t2=clock();

    A=clock();
    md=maxSubArraySum(array, 0, n-1) ;
    B=clock();

    K1=clock();
    qq=Kedane(array, n);
    K2=clock();


 cout<< n << "," << (double)t2-(double)t1 << ","<<(double)B-(double)A << ","<<(double)K2-(double)K1<<endl;

}

return 0;
```

}

```
101,0,0,0
201,0,0,0
301,1,0,0
401,0,0,0
501,0,0,0
601,0,0,0
701,0,0,0
801,1,0,0
901,1,0,0
1001,0,0,0
1101,1,0,0
1201,1,0,0
1301,0,0,0
1401,1,0,0
1501,1,0,0
1601,2,0,0
1701,1,0,0
1801,2,0,0
1901,1,1,0
2001,1,0,0
2101,2,0,0
2201,3,0,0
2301,2,0,0
2401,3,0,0
2501,3,0,0
2601,3,0,0
2701,4,0,0
2801,4,0,0
2901,4,0,0
3001,4,0,0
3101,4,0,0
3201,5,0,0
3301,5,0,0
3401,6,0,0
3501,5,0,0
3601,6,0,0
3701,6,0,0
3801,8,0,0
3901,7,0,0
4001,8,0,0
4101,7,0,0
4201,10,1,0
4301,9,0,0
4401,8,0,0
4501,9,0,0
4601,10,0,0
4701,11,0,0
4801,11,0,0
4901,11,0,0
5001,12,0,1
5101,11,1,0
5201,13,0,0
5301,13,0,0
5401,15,0,0
5501,14,0,0
5601,16,0,0
5701,15,0,0
5801,15,1,0
5901,16,0,0
6001,17,0,0
6101,18,0,0
6201,18,0,0
6301,19,0,0
6401,21,0,0
6501,19,0,0
6601,21,1,0
6701,20,0,0
6801,22,0,0
6901,23,0,0
7001,22,0,0
7101,24,0,0
7201,26,0,0
7301,26,0,0
7401,24,1,0
7501,26,0,0
7601,27,0,0
7701,28,0,0
7801,28,0,0
7901,30,0,0
8001,29,0,0
8101,31,0,0
8201,31,1,0
8301,35,0,0
8401,33,0,0
8501,35,0,0
8601,35,1,0
8701,35,0,0
8801,36,1,0
8901,37,0,0
9001,38,0,0
9101,39,0,0
9201,41,1,0
9301,40,0,0
9401,41,0,0
9501,42,0,0
9601,45,0,0
9701,45,0,0
9801,44,0,0
9901,47,0,0
10001,47,0,0
10101,48,0,0
10201,50,0,0
10301,51,0,0
10401,50,0,0
10501,51,0,0
10601,53,0,0
10701,55,0,0
10801,54,0,0
10901,56,0,0
11001,57,0,0
11101,56,0,0
11201,60,0,0
11301,60,0,0
11401,61,1,0
11501,61,1,0
11601,63,0,0
11701,62,1,0
11801,66,1,0
11901,65,0,0
12001,68,1,0
12101,68,0,0
12201,70,0,0
12301,71,0,0
12401,72,0,0
12501,73,1,0
12601,73,1,0
12701,76,0,0
12801,77,0,0
12901,78,1,0
13001,79,1,0
13101,80,0,0
13201,83,0,0
13301,82,0,0
13401,86,0,0
13501,85,1,0
13601,86,0,0
13701,89,0,0
13801,90,0,1
13901,90,0,0
14001,91,0,0
14101,97,0,0
14201,93,0,0
14301,96,0,0
14401,99,0,0
14501,100,0,0
14601,101,0,0
14701,101,0,0
14801,103,1,0
14901,104,0,0
15001,107,0,0
15101,108,0,0
15201,109,0,0
15301,109,0,0
15401,114,0,0
15501,114,0,0
15601,115,0,0
15701,116,0,0
15801,119,0,0
15901,118,0,0
16001,124,0,0
16101,123,1,0
16201,123,1,0
16301,125,0,0
16401,127,1,0
16501,128,1,0
16601,131,0,0
16701,132,0,0
16801,134,0,0
16901,134,1,0
17001,135,1,0
17101,139,0,0
17201,139,0,0
17301,140,1,0
17401,143,0,0
17501,145,0,0
17601,147,0,0
17701,147,0,0
17801,150,1,0
17901,152,1,0
18001,153,0,0
18101,155,0,0
18201,157,0,0
18301,157,1,0
18401,160,0,0
18501,160,1,0
18601,163,1,0
18701,165,0,0
18801,169,0,0
18901,171,0,1
19001,170,1,0
19101,173,1,0
19201,178,0,0
19301,175,1,0
19401,176,1,0
19501,180,0,0
19601,180,1,0
19701,182,1,0
19801,184,0,0
19901,187,1,0
20001,188,1,0
20101,191,0,0
20201,192,1,0
20301,193,1,0
20401,195,0,0
20501,199,0,0
20601,200,0,0
20701,201,0,0
20801,209,1,0
20901,210,0,0
21001,206,0,0
21101,210,0,0
21201,210,0,0
21301,213,0,0
21401,215,1,0
21501,217,1,0
21601,218,1,0
21701,221,1,0
21801,222,1,0
21901,226,1,0
22001,225,1,0
22101,229,0,0
22201,232,0,0
22301,233,1,0
22401,234,1,0
22501,237,1,0
22601,238,0,1
22701,243,0,0
22801,242,1,0
22901,246,1,0
23001,246,0,0
23101,250,1,0
23201,250,1,0
23301,254,1,0
23401,254,0,0
23501,259,0,1
23601,260,1,0
23701,263,1,0
23801,268,0,0
23901,266,1,0
24001,271,0,0
24101,272,1,0
24201,274,1,0
24301,280,0,1
24401,279,0,0
24501,281,0,0
24601,285,0,0
24701,288,0,0
24801,289,0,0
24901,293,0,0
25001,295,1,0
25101,299,1,0
25201,299,1,0
25301,302,0,0
25401,305,1,0
25501,307,0,0
25601,310,1,0
25701,315,0,0
25801,312,1,0
25901,315,0,0
26001,320,1,0
26101,320,0,0
26201,322,0,0
26301,327,1,0
26401,329,0,0
26501,332,1,0
26601,339,1,0
26701,334,1,0
26801,337,0,0
26901,340,0,0
27001,341,1,0
27101,342,1,0
27201,347,0,0
27301,348,1,0
27401,351,1,0
27501,353,0,0
27601,356,1,0
27701,360,0,1
27801,361,1,0
27901,362,1,0
28001,366,1,0
28101,370,0,1
28201,372,0,0
28301,375,1,0
28401,377,1,0
28501,380,0,0
28601,384,1,0
28701,384,0,0
28801,388,1,0
28901,391,1,0
29001,392,1,0
29101,399,1,0
29201,399,0,0
29301,404,1,0
29401,405,0,0
29501,409,1,0
29601,412,2,0
29701,412,1,0
29801,422,1,0
29901,419,1,0
```

Comment: @chux changed! thankyou

Comment: "...  output it gives me is correct ..."  Suggest posting the output  ( and formatting the code).

Comment: On my compiler (MSVC 2015) the BruteForce function is inlined and runs REALLY fast. I believe "less than one clock tick" is the correct time!

Comment: yea, I noticed the same thing Im wondering if the example is quite old and therefore isnt as optimised because the timings are alot longer on the output i was given.

Answer (score 0):

The return values from `BruteForce` and `maxSubArraySum` are never used, and this gives the compiler a lot of lattitude when it comes to optimizing them.

On my machine for example, using clang -O3 reduces the call to `BruteForce` to a vector copy and nothing else.

One method for forcing the evaluation of these functions is to write their results to volatile variables:

```
volatile int mb, md;
// ...
    mb = BruteForce(array, n);
    // ...
    md = maxSubArraySum(array, 0, n-1);
```

As the variables are volatile, the value given by the right-hand side of the assignments must be stored, despite the absence of any other side-effects, which prevents the compiler from optimising the computation away.

Comment: Oh I see, Now ive done that with my modifictions to my code (posted above) im gettign a value for the `BruteForce` but `0`'s and `1`'s for `maxSubArraySum` and `Kedane`.
Could it work, by say using the values `mb` etc printing them to a file just so i am using them?

Comment: Without further testing, I'm guessing you're just getting very small timings for the other two functions. Before looking for more exotic solutions, I'd try putting them in a timing loop, e.g. `volatile int m; A=clock(); for (int i=0; i<1000; ++i) m=the_function(); B=clock();`